# MySQL query to update records with incremented date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, sql-date-functions

I am trying to

1. get the latest date in a database, and
2. based on that date update every record that has a `NULL` date, increasing the date by 1 day.

I can get the latest date by using the **Latest Date** query below. I need to do this first because the dates in the table are **not** in order. If need be, I can run this query, manually write it down, then run the `UPDATE` query based on this date. I would prefer to run everything without the manual process.

The last query I have at the bottom of the question is my *test query* for trying to update the dates, however I had no luck getting it to work.

**Table (dates are not in order)**

```
id     date
-----  ----------
10500  2013-08-18
10501  2013-08-16
10502  2013-08-17
10503  2013-08-19
10504  NULL
10505  NULL
...
11800  NULL
11801  NULL
```

**Selecting the latest date (starting point for `UPDATE`)**

```sql
SELECT date
FROM my_table
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Updating `NULL` dates (*doesn't work*)**

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET date = DATE_ADD((SELECT date FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE date IS NULL
ORDER BY id ASC
```

How can I accomplish this? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Do you want to have the same date for all ids with corresponding dates that are NULL, or you want to increment the date from row to row?

Comment: @peterm Increment the date from row to row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN
(
  SELECT id, @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM Table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
   WHERE date IS NULL
   ORDER BY id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(date) date FROM Table1
) q
   SET t1.date = q.date + INTERVAL t2.rnum DAY
```

Result:

```
|    ID |       DATE |
----------------------
| 10500 | 2013-08-18 |
| 10501 | 2013-08-16 |
| 10502 | 2013-08-17 |
| 10503 | 2013-08-19 |
| 10504 | 2013-08-20 | --  date has been assigned
| 10505 | 2013-08-21 | --  date has been assigned
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cf27/1)** demo

Explanation: *In a subquery with an alias t2 we grab all rows where date IS NULL order them by `id` and assign row numbers starting from 1. Unfortunately MySql doesn't have an implementation for `ROW_NUMBER()` function so we do it with a user variable `@n` which is incremented while rows are selected. To initialize this variable we use a subquery with an alias `i`. And use `CROSS JOIN` to make it available for our subquery `t2`. We then use the same technique (`CROSS JOIN`) to grab a max date in the table and make it available for every row in our `JOIN`. ONce we have all that we just add a line number,  which represents a number of days) add it to the max date and assign to `date` column in our table.*

Comment: Great. Looks like it works. Do you mind explaining the query a bit so I understand what is happening here?

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason you are not using `AS` for aliases?

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :) The reason for that it's just shorter and less clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` syntax instead:

```
UPDATE my_table cross join
       (SELECT max(date) as maxdate FROM my_table) const
SET my_table.date = DATE_ADD(const.maxdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE my_table.date IS NULL;
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this works only on the next record, after that it does not increment and I get a duplicate entry error since the dates cannot be the same.