# mySQL update next 12 NULL values with date increment by 1

Tags: mysql, sql, date, auto-increment

Basically, I have these 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE langue = 'fr' AND hDate IS NULL
LIMIT 12;

UPDATE table
SET hDate = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE hDate IS NULL
LIMIT 12;
```

These works good for first 12 NULL records. If I need to update next 12 NULL records I have to manually change the UPDATE query to INTERVAL 2 DAY

Problem is that I have 4000 records.

I have tried

```
UPDATE table t1 JOIN
(
  SELECT id, @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM table CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
  WHERE langue = 'fr'
  ORDER BY id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(hDate) sdate FROM table 
) q
   SET t1.hDate = q.sdate + INTERVAL t2.rnum DAY
```

from this answer: [MySQL query to update records with incremented date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244805/mysql-query-to-update-records-with-incremented-date)

but this increments each record with 1 day. I have to increment 12 records with same date, next 12 records with date + 1, next 12 records with date + 2 etc.

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `texte` mediumtext,
  `langue` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6726 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: All hDate are NULL at first. I have to increment first 12 records with same date (today), next 12 records with today + 1, next 12 records with today + 2 etc. until the end of 4000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a554/1

```
SET @i:=0;
SET @j:=0;

UPDATE t1

RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 
     id
     ,IF(@j = 0 ,@j:=1, @j:=@j+1)
     ,IF((@j-1) % 12 = 0, @i:= @i+1, @i)  as i
  FROM t1
  WHERE hDate IS NULL
) idx
on idx.id = t1.id
  SET t1.hDate = CURDATE() + INTERVAL (idx.i)  DAY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! All works good except for IF(@j % 12 = 0. I think it should be IF(@j % 12 = 1. If no, the first group will have 11 records updated. Also your sql fiddle link doesn't work.

Comment: My bad. Fixed. :-) But keep in mind that this trick is not the best example from performance perspective. So if number of records will grow that query becomes very slow

Comment: For 4400 records it is executing at 0.219 sec. Thanks again.